# static file not served in heroku app

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-templates

I deployed my final working project to heroku.

The problem is only html content loading, Static files are missing. I tried lots but missing something. Can you spot the error.

```
# .. settings.py

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give the **STATIC_ROOT** ...(It can not be empty). Because the "HEROKU", always run 'collectstatic' while deploying.. and it creates the folder like as 'static files' and all the process running by the way of this folder contents.